# Writing bi-directional text to a text file in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to write the following strings to a text file:

```
str1 = "אבג IMM:";
str2 = "3492";
```

To make things clearer, let's say `a = "אבג"`, `b = "IMM:"`. What I'm trying to write to the text file is `a + b + str2`.

What I'm actually getting is `a + str2 + b`

I thought I'd find an easy answer in google but couldn't so I'm stuck with this silly little issue.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Edit:

Thanks for the quick responses. This is an example of my code:

```
try {
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("newtxt.txt");
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter
      (out,"UNICODE"));
    String str1 = "אבג IMM:";
    String str2 = "3492";
    String newStr = str1 + str2;
    writer.write(newStr);
    writer.close();
} catch(IOException ex) {}
```

Things to keep in mind:

- I'm writing this bit of text to an existing file with mostly right to left text, so while this text displays properly in left to right, the problem is there.
- Manually writing this bit of text in notepad also proves problematic. Manually writing in a more advanced program such as Microsoft's Word, and the problem is gone. However, as the code is written right now, saving the file as a doc / rtf type doesn't solve this problem.
- There's no problem appending english to hebrew and vise versa, with no numbers.

Comment: That's strange.. Can you show how you are doing it with some code?

Comment: Can you paste your sample code. It really looks very strange.

Comment: I have the feeling your code is writing the text correctly, and when you view the results, a trick of Bidi is causing the characters to appear in a visual order that is not the same as their order in the file.  For instance, most English-speaking programmers would not realize that the first character of the string `"אבג"` is `'א'`.

Comment: your string-a has right-to-left characters, and what you see will depend upon how you are displaying it, so include details on whether you are viewing this in an HTML page, or in System.out, or whatever.